# How to hide credit card option using PayPal checkout

Tags: javascript, paypal, checkout

I'm following the example on the [Quick Start](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/quick-start/) page, which shows the following code:

```
<div id="paypal-button"></div>
<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>
<script>
paypal.Button.render({
  env: 'sandbox',
  client: {
    sandbox: 'demo_sandbox_client_id'
  },
  payment: function (data, actions) {
    return actions.payment.create({
      transactions: [{
        amount: {
          total: '0.01',
          currency: 'USD'
        }
      }]
    });
  },
  onAuthorize: function (data, actions) {
    return actions.payment.execute()
      .then(function () {
        window.alert('Thank you for your purchase!');
      });
  }
}, '#paypal-button');
</script>
```

I would like to remove the option to pay by credit card, and only allow the user to pay using their PayPal credit - how do I do this?

Comment: I don’t think that is possible using the checkout flow. Plus, why? As long as I pay you what’s owed, of what particular interest is the specific method of paying I use to you …?

Comment: @CBroe good question, but that's what my client asked for...

Comment: We had a client ask for this a couple of months back, in combination with a PrestaShop setup and the official PP-plugin they provide. I called PayPal support and asked, but they said with the normal checkout that option wasn’t available, and the customer would have to switch to some more powerful/extensive option for that to become available. (I don’t remember the specific details, but that was more or less the gist of it.)

Comment: @CBroe Great answer - please write as answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had a client ask for this a couple of months back, in combination with a PrestaShop setup and the official PayPal plugin they provide.

I called PayPal support and asked, but they said with the normal checkout that option wasn’t available, and the customer would have to switch to some more powerful/extensive option for that to become available. (I don’t remember the specific details, but that was more or less the gist of it.)

---

Not sure how much that might differ based on what countries one operates in, what exact PayPal options are “booked” in the account, etc. If your customer desperately wants this, then I’d recommend you contact PayPal support yourself with all the details, to have them confirm whether there is absolutely no way, or if there are specific circumstances/options ...

Answer (score 3):

You can use path `disable-funding=credit,card` in `src` of script link as:
`<script src="https://paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&disable-funding=credit,card"></script>`

I have found the answer at this link:
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/122385

Source:
 https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/customize-sdk/#disable-funding